# Can $x^{2q}$ be irrational for rational $x$ and $q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

I think the answer to the question in the title is "yes", because $9^{2/3}$ is irrational by an argument similar to the accepted answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102348/how-can-one-prove-that-the-cube-root-of-9-is-irrational). Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes. Or $x = 2$, $q = 1/4$

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question.  Yes, your answer is correct

Comment: Actually, it'd be quite interesting to know how 'big' is the set of irrationals with this form.

Answer (score 3):

... Yep. For example, $x = 2$, $q = \frac{1}{4}$.

$2^{2(1/4)} = 2^{1/2}$, an irrational number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it *can* be, x=1. But, it is not necessarily rational, as Simon S. pointed out, x=2, q=1/4.