# Is there a rational way to conceptualize an irrational number?

Tags: irrational-numbers

This is a request for help, not an attempt to challenge anything.

Since $\pi$ is irrational, this tells me that it's *impossible* to express the distance around a circle in terms of the distance accross.

That boggles my mind, but maybe it should not.

I think crazy thoughts like: *"this means that a the path of a circle around a unit lenth line segment has a non existant length".*

Is there a way to accept that the number is irrational and not break from reason?

Comment: Knowing what [rational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) and [irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) actually mean would be a good start. The irrationality of $\pi$ certainly does not mean that it's impossible to express the circumference of a circle in terms of the diameter.

Comment: apologies.. maybe i have to delete this

Comment: Why it tells you that it is impossible to express it? You can express it using $\pi$. You can't say that is is a nonexistant length it is just a length that is not a fraction. Like the length of the diagonal of the unit square. Nothing special.

Comment: What do you mean by non existant length...  We have something existing number for circumference of circle... But we can't express it in decimal representation... and that is why we call it Irrational number..

Comment: Irrationality doesn't imply non-existence. In fact, Although mathematically non-rigorous, if the stars in the night sky were rational numbers, the dark background would be the irrationals. An irrational number simply implies inability to express it as a ratio of integers.

Comment: OK, i was thinking that C = PI * d so a circle that is 1 accross is PI around... and PI is irrational... what am I goofing up here?

Comment: The above seems right.

Comment: Nothing.  A circle with radius $1$ has circumference $\pi$.

Comment: @PradipMishra We do not call numbers without decimal representation irrational. ($1/3=0.33333\ldots$ is rational but has no representation) We call numbers irrational if they are not rational, so they are not a ratio $a/b$ of some integers $a,b$.

Comment: You're not alone in the bewilderment. The idea of [incommensurability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(mathematics)) (what we now refer to as irrationality) was a struggle for the Ancient Greeks. They knew, for example, that the diagonal of a square was incommensurable with its side (a fact that we express today as "the square root of two is irrational"), but struggled for a long time to show that the area of a circle was incommensurable with the square on its diameter ("squaring the circle") which led them to doubt whether the concept of curvilinear area was meaningful at all!

Comment: $saviko1,  I agree..

Comment: It's of interest to note that the modern connotation of "irrational" arose from the consternation expressed  by those who first realized $\sqrt 2$ is *not* a *ratio* (of integers), at least according to some sources...

Comment: My experience is that most people graduate high school with only a vague and often confused notion of irrational numbers and the elemental properties of the reals.  I attribute this to a bad education system, as anyone of average intelligence can understand it if they are willing to listen.

Answer (score 4):

That $\pi$ is irrational does not mean that it's impossible to express the distance around a circle in terms of the distance across.  It only means it can't be expressed as a ratio of integers.

BTW [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) you can read some proofs that $\pi$ is irrational.

It is quite easy to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.  It's even easier to prove that $\log_2 3$ is irrational.  But it's hard to prove $\pi$ is irrational.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62878/proving-irrationality) is a related question that may be of interest, where you will read about how to prove some numbers are irrational.

Answer (score 2):

Some numbers are indeed impossible to express. Those are the numbers that are not [definable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_number). Easier to deal with, but still difficult, are numbers that are not [computable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number).

However, it is not so difficult to provide a clear definition of the quotient of the circle's circumference by its diameter. We can let the matter stand there and simply name the quotient "pi", or we can do like Archimedes and define that quotient to be the limit of the regular polygon's perimeter to its diameter (using either choice of the inner or outer diameter) as the number of sides approaches infinity. We have the epsilon-and-delta definition of limits to help convince us that this is a valid definition.

Comment: I disagree.  Some non-computable numbers are expressible.

Comment: Michael Hardy, I'm sure your objection is correct. I have edited my answer in an attempt to be more accurate.

Comment: out of curiousity, what is an example of a non-computable yet expressible number?

Comment: Chaitin's omega is expressible but not computable because it measures halting probability. The halting problem is famously not solvable by computation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, contrarywise, is there any reason why $\pi$ *should* be a rational number?  A rational number just means it's expressible as a ratio between two whole numbers.  Is there a reason that $\pi$ (or any other arbitrary value) *need* to be expressible a ratio of two whole numbers?

Well, I can think of two intuitive (but *wrong*) reasons.  But I want to express that, in a way, irrational numbers intuitively make *more* sense than rational numbers.

Consider distance and space.  Surely it is a continuum and every *possible* distance is going to exist and they are infinite.  There aren't any holes and jumps between points.  So let's say you put up a sign here and say "This is here!" and one mile you put up a sign saying "this is one mile" and you put sign post each exactly splitting the mile into 6 parts so you have posts every 1/6 mile.

Now take a pea-shooter and shoot it anywhere randomly to the mile line.  Where does the pea land.  Well, if it hit exactly one of the sign posts that'd be kind of unlikely.  So says someone (there's always someone)we can split the distance into smaller pieces, into 60ths of miles 120ths miles, thousands of miles, 573th of a mile.  But is there any reason why the pea should match up *perfectly* with any of those?  In fact doesn't it seem *un*likely?

Okay, here come Pythagoras just walking down the street (what's he doing here? Don't ask) and he says "Everything is whole  numbers; there must be some precise number that cuts this mile to precisely that point."  And you say to him "Why?  Where did you get that idea?  Why should that be?"  And he basically says it'd make life perfect and nice and it'd be religiously beautiful if it were so.

Well, okay, but what about $\sqrt 2$ you say.  He gets a dirty look and suddenly you are very, very glad you are not on a boat.

Okay, that was a fantasy.  I think in a naive and simplistic way it's intuitive to think that because we can split an apple into rational number parts, it should work the other way, and we should be able to take any value and find the parts that broke it away from the whole.  But we shouldn't assume naive ideas and if we view numbers as *continuum* distance, instead of *discrete* apples and distinct apple slices. It *shouldn't* be intuitive anymore.

Consider decimals.  To get from 3.7 to 3.8 you have to pass through 3.75 first and to get to 3.75 you must go through 3.726 and each precision deeper there are infinite degrees of precision.  As we *swim* past them we are going from point to point *continually*.  The Pythagorases of the world would have as *jumping* from descrete whole number slice to whole number slice.  There isn't any reason to think that this is the correct way to view this.  And, it turns out, it *isn't* the correct way to view.

What is reality? Is it swimming through a continuum, or is it jumping from precise knife cut to knife cut?

So numbers are a *continuum* and there exist infinitely *many* numbers that simply aren't a discrete j/k amount for a precise whole number of exactly $1/k$ slices.  And why shouldn't there be?

Answer (score -1):

**Irrational numbers can and do correspond to length**

Yes. An irrational number is a number that cannot be expressed as a ratio between two integers. It does exist as a length. For example, $\sqrt{2}$ is famously irrational, but it is extremely easy to show it as a length: just draw the diagonal of a square of side $1$.

**Conceptualisation of irrational numbers**

The whole rational vs irrational business started in ancient Greece. The Pythagoreans (the members of a secret group of mathematicians) believed that the whole universe could be described in terms of whole numbers: $1,2,3,4,...$
They were doing geometry, and they realised that some lengths were not integer multiples of other ones (more than $2$ times as long, but not quite $3$ times).

That's when they invented *ratios*: relationships between numbers. For example, $2$ is to $3$ just like $4$ is to $6$, in the sense that if you were to draw a rectangle with sides $2$ and $3$ and, next to it, one with sides $4$ and $6$, they would *look the same* (try it!). We express that relationship, by saying:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{6}
\end{equation}

Since they have faith in the integers, they believed that *any* length could be understood this way, two lengths coming from the simplest shapes: the circumference of the circle of diameter $1$ and the diagonal of the square of side $1$.

Now you know that it turns out that both $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are irrationals. So what does it mean?  It just means that it cannot be expressed as a ratio!

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1E7I7_r3Cw) for a brilliant exploration of all of this!