# Why is the sequence $ a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $ Cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I was looking at the post:

[Cauchy Sequence that Does Not Converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119307/cauchy-sequence-that-does-not-converge)

And the top answer was this sequence:

$ a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. I understand that this sequence converges to $e$, which is not a rational number, and that $a_n$ is a sequence of rationals, but I don't see why that proves that $a_n$ it is Cauchy. I wonder if someone could give another explanation of why $a_n$ is Cauchy using the following definition:

A sequence $p_n$ is Cauchy if $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M \in R$ such that $\forall i, j \in N:$

$i,j > M \implies \mid p_i - p_j \mid < \epsilon$

EDIT: I originally asked the opposite of what I meant to asked. My apologies...

Comment: I think you're missing part of your equation.

Comment: Why do you think anybody is suggesting that it's not Cauchy?

Comment: Ya I actually mistyped that. I'll rephrase...

Comment: I actually the totally wrong question. I meant to ask: why IS the sequence Cauchy, using the definition. Whoops!

Comment: Then just edit your question to ask what you meant to ask, rather than keeping an incorrect version of it in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In $\Bbb Q$ this sequence does not converge. In $\Bbb R$ it does. The sequence is Cauchy, regardless.

Comment: Got it. So if $Q$ is my metric space, with $d(x,y)=\mid x-y \mid$. Then I have a Cauchy sequence that does not converge. Correct?

Comment: Yes. you can rephrase this saying that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete with respect to the metric $|\cdot|$

Comment: But if $a_n$ doesn't converge in $Q$, why is it still Cauchy in $Q$?

Comment: For the same reason it is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$: because it satisfies the condition for being Cauchy.

Comment: I think you're forgetting that the equivalence "Cauchy $\iff$ convergent" only holds in a complete metric space (e.g., $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 3):

This sequence converges to $e$. Since it converges, it is necessarily Cauchy.

Suppose $x_n\to l$ as $n\to\infty$. Choose $\epsilon > 0$.  Then there is some $N$ so $n\ge N\implies |x_n -l| < \epsilon/2$.  Choose $m, n \ge N$. Then
$$|x_m - x_n| \le |x_n-l| + |x_m - l| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.$$
The sequence is Cauchy.