# Show that the metric space $(\Bbb N, d)$ with $d(m,n)=1+\frac{1}{m+n}$ if $m \ne n$ and $d(m,n)=0$ if $m=n$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be metric on $\Bbb N$ defined by
$$d(m,n) =
\begin{cases}
1+\frac{1}{m+n}, m \ne n; \\
0, m = n.
\end{cases}$$
Show that the metric space $(\Bbb N, d)$ is complete.

**Attempt:**
Let $(x_n)$ be an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $(\Bbb N, d)$.
Then $d(x_m,x_n) \to 0$ as $m,n \to \infty$.
Now, if $x_m \ne x_n$, then $d(x_m,x_n) = 1+\frac{1}{x_m+x_n}>1 \not\to 0$.
Hence, we must have $x_m=x_n$ and so, $d(x_m,x_n)=0<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, for all $m,n \ge N$, and for some positive integer $N$.
Thus, $(x_n)$ is convergent in $(\Bbb N, d)$.
Therefore, $(\Bbb N, d)$ is a complete metric space.

Does this works?

Comment: The proof is correct, but it can be made more rigorous (and clear) by explicitly setting the $N$ s.t. $\forall m,n\ge N, d(x_m, x_n)<1$.

Answer (score 1):

While it has, in some essence, the key realizations, I don't think this constitutes a complete proof.

Your goal is to show that, provided $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, that it converges.

What does it mean for $(x_n)$ to converge, though? It means - in this space - that there is some $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Showing that $d(x_m,x_n) \to 0$ doesn't help anything -- in fact, you're already assuming that at the start, so you've not shown anything. *(Especially considering that [there exist Cauchy sequences which are not convergent in some spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119307/cauchy-sequence-that-does-not-converge).)* You need to find a prospective limit of the sequence -- and then prove, indeed, that it is the limit.

You have made the key realization that, if at any point in the sequence, we have $x_m \ne x_n$, then $d(x_m,x_n) > 1$. Consequently, there has to be some integer $N$ beyond which this stops, in the sense that $d(x_m,x_n) = 0$ for $m,n \ge N$ (because the sequence is supposed Cauchy).

The questions remain, then:

- Why can I immediately say that $d(x_m,x_n) = 0$ and not just $d(x_m,x_n) \le 1$? *(Pull back to your definition of $d$.)*
- What does this imply for the sequence $(x_n)$ and its behavior? *(Try playing with a few examples of sequences.)*
- Consequently, what does this imply the limit of $(x_n)$ should be? And what is the proof that this limit is, indeed, the limit?