# Proof any periodic number is rational.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Is there a proof that any number of the form $a_1.a_2\overline{a_3}$ where we are contatenating them and they are all finite sequences of digits is rational?

Regards.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61937/how-can-i-prove-that-all-rational-numbers-are-either-terminally-real-or-repeatin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any periodic (as you call it) number can be written in the form $ r + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b 10^{k-nl}$ where $r$ is some rational number, $b,k$ are integers and $l$ is a positive integer.

Example 1.23454545... has $r=1.23, b=45, k=-4, l=2$.

But $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b 10^{k-nl}$ is sum of geometric series with a common ratio of $10^{-l}$.

Since $l\geq1$, we get $10^{l}\geq10 $ or $0<\frac1{10^{l}}\leq\frac1{10}<1$ and thus we have the convergent series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b 10^{k-nl} = b 10^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(10^{-l}\right)^n = b 10^k \frac1{1-10^{-l}} $$

That is certainly a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_3$ consists of $k$ digits, multiply the number with $10^k$ and subtract. The difference is a termininating decimal, i.e. a rational number with at most a power of $10$ as denominator.

Comment: could you elaborate please?