# Prime numbers which 1/p has decimal period of p-1

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

How to find prime numbers where $\frac{1}{p}$ has decimal period of $p-1$? Is there any formula? please help.
**Example**: $\frac{1}{7}=0.142857142857...$ with decimal period of $7-1=6$ also $17$ satisfies this condition, but $13$ does not.

Comment: You need to check that $10$ is a generator $\pmod p$, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).  there is no known method to efficiently list these.

Comment: wow did you cook up this problem?

Comment: I guess there should be a formula like the formula of "full reptend primes"

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/61947/242)